# Restoring a Mysql database that is 7zip

Tags: backup-restoration, mysql

I use

**Mysqldump –u root –ppassword databasename | 7z a -si -t7z outputfile.sql.7z -mx9**

To backup my Mysql 5.1 database on my windows vista system.

**Question:**

How can I restore the database without first having to expand the 7zip file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not that familar with the 7zip command line  but I suspect you would do something like this.

```
7z e -so outputfile.sql.7z | mysql -u username -p databasename
```